# Runtime Error 5148 - To print selected page from code

Tags: excel, ms-word, vba

I am trying to print word document selected page from excel VBA, The page number will be get from input msg box. I am getting Runtime ERROR 5148.

Kindly help me in this.

```
Dim directory As String, fileName As String, ans As String, i As Integer
Dim objWord As Object
Dim intpage As Integer, intcopies As Integer

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
objWord.Visible = True

' path to the folder
directory = "E:\print\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.doc*") ' Open Multiple Word Docs Both .doc and .docx
Do While fileName <> ""
    objWord.Documents.Open (directory & fileName)

    On Error Resume Next
    intpage = CInt(InputBox("Which page to print?"))
    intcopies = CInt(InputBox("How many copies?"))
    On Error GoTo 0

    If intpage * intcopies <> 0 Then
       For i = 1 To intcopies ' Loop to print next page of uer Choice Note: simplex is not working in my Office, Default Duplex

       '### HERE IS THE PROBLEM###
        objWord.PrintOut Range:=wdPrintRangeOfPages, Pages:=intpage

        Next
    Else
        MsgBox "sorry, wrong page or copies, try again"
    End If
        'Next
    objWord.Documents.Close
        'set file to next in Dir
    fileName = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: `wdPrintRangeOfPages` is a constant defined in the Word object library - Excel does not know what it is.  either add a reference to the Word library, or substitute the actual value.

Comment: I am a learner,i dont know how to code, can you suggest exact code

Comment: Put `4` in place of `wdPrintRangeOfPages`

Comment: Now i am getting type mismatch error

Comment: Yes on same line Tim

Comment: What's the value of `intpage` when it fails?  Don't have a printer here, so I can't test your code.

Comment: I am checking with 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
objWord.PrintOut Range:=4, Pages:=CStr(intpage) '4=wdPrintRangeOfPages
```

Note: `PrintOut` also has a `Copies` parameter which you could use instead of looping.